# Duplicate class kotlinx.android.parcel.IgnoredOnParcel found in modules kotlin-android-extensions-runtime and kotlin-parcelize-runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

```
     Duplicate class kotlinx.android.parcel.IgnoredOnParcel 
    found in modules kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.3.72
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.72) 
    and kotlin-parcelize-runtime-1.4.20-RC 
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-parcelize-runtime:1.4.20-RC)
```

#### I have removed *kotlin-android-extensions* and added *kotilin-parcelize*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found the Answer**
The problem was kotlin developers deprecated **kotlin-android-extensions** and added separate dependencies for each of them like  **kotilin-parcelize** also they shifted the classes from
import **kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize** to **kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize**

Answer (score 0):

One of your dependency library is duplicating.
If you want to find the duplication dependency, you can use gradlew from Android Studio Terminal
task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

or

you can follow
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolution_errors

If you want to keep your library after you find it has duplicate references
you can check the following to exclude those

> implementation ("duplicate dependency library") {
> exclude(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module = "kotlin-reflect")
> }

for example:

```
implementation ("com.daveanthonythomas.moshipack:moshipack:1.0.1") {
    exclude(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module = "kotlin-reflect")
}
```